# Query slow on Phpmyadmin but query execution time on mysql is fast

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When I execute resquests on specific views, returning small number of results (30 results), the query is executed instantaneously on mysql (eg. 0.009), but display in phpmyadmin lasts for minutes (even if displayed execution time is the same)

Some tables used by the view have large number of records.

Looking deeply on phpmyadmin code, I found out that the culprit is this part of code in library/classes/Display/Results.php

```
        /**
         * The result set can have columns from more than one table,
         * this is why we have to check for the unique conditions
         * related to this table; however getUniqueCondition() is
         * costly and does not need to be called if we already know
         * the conditions for the current table.
         */
        if (! isset($whereClauseMap[$rowNumber][$meta->orgtable])) {
            [$uniqueConditions] = Util::getUniqueCondition(
                $this->properties['fields_cnt'],
                $this->properties['fields_meta'],
                $row,
                false,
                $meta->orgtable,
                $expressions,
            );
            $whereClauseMap[$rowNumber][$meta->orgtable] = $uniqueConditions;
        }
```

What the purpose to check the unique conditions related to the table?

Is there any workaround?

Comment: Find the query, then `EXPLAIN {query}`. And `SHOW CREATE TABLE {tablename}` on the tables involved.

Comment: PMA uses this method to figure out how to uniquely identify a row in edit/delete links when displaying a table of results. There does not appear to be any way to stop it running this method. You could switch to using a tool like [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/) or, if you need it to run on your web server, maybe [Adminer](https://www.adminer.org/)?

Comment: @danblack, the problem is not the query itself but the actions that phpmyadmin is performing before displaying the results.